# pass buttonClick method as parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, event-handling, devexpress

I want to pass buttonClick method as a parameter to the function:
we have

buttonClick:

```
private void iDeactivate_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
 ...
}
```

function:

```
private void AddItemToPopUpMenu(GridViewMenu cMenu, string cItemCaption, EventHandler cClickHandler, Image cItemImage, bool cItemBeginGroup)
{
    DXMenuItem item = new DXMenuItem();
    item.Caption = cItemCaption;
    item.Click += new EventHandler(cClickHandler); //problem there
    item.Image = cItemImage;
    item.BeginGroup = cItemBeginGroup;
    cMenu.Items.Add(item);
}
```

So can someone suggest solution?

tried:

```
AddItemToPopUpMenu(cMenu, iDeaActive.Caption, iDeactivate_ItemClick, null, false);
```

and changing function parameters to:

```
private void AddItemToPopUpMenu(GridViewMenu cMenu, string cItemCaption, EventHandler<ItemClickEventArgs> cClickHandler, Image cItemImage, bool cItemBeginGroup)
```

but then I get mistake in code where I have marked "problem there"

So is it possible to pass buttonClick method, without changing it parameters?

Edit:
As I see some wrong answers, so should say that Ihave to pass as a parameter because AddItemToPopUpMenu is called several times, every time with different methods

Comment: Can you tell us what problem you get? E.g. a compiler error, or an exception at runtime, and what the message you get is?

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler<DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs>' to 'System.EventHandler' D:\matrix\XPO\MxProject\Matrix.MxProject.Win\SearchForms\BaseSearchForm.cs 1243 27 Matrix.MxProject.Win

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the look of it, [`DXMenuItem.Click`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressUtilsMenuDXMenuItem_Clicktopic) only supplies a regular `EventArgs` object and such can only work with regular `EventHandlers`.

You're trying to get a specialized [`DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsItemClickEventArgstopic) object in your handler, and the event just *doesn't supply it*.

I don't think what you're trying to do is possible. You either need to reduce your handler so it only needs a regular `EventArgs`, or you need to find a type of button whose `Click` event supplies an `ItemClickEventArgs`.

Comment: I'm not so sure about this now - I just checked and you can quite happily construct an `EventHandler` from an `EventHandler` - although not from an `EventHandler<T>`. Let me know if this doesn't help and I'll delete it.

Comment: not it does not work(Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler<DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs>' to 'System.EventHandler' D:\matrix\XPO\MxProject\Matrix.MxProject.Win\SearchForms\BaseSearchForm.cs 1243 27 Matrix.MxProject.Win
)

Comment: Does it work if you change your function parameter back to an `EventHandler` rather than an `EventHandler<ItemClickEventArgs>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign method name directly to your event, provided that the signature matches the delegate required by the event

```
item.Click += iDeactivate_ItemClick;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
item.Click += cClickHandler;
```

Will be enought for you as you already passed delegate